# Change page layout at begin of each page

Tags: margins, geometry, atbegshi

I want to have very different page layout for even and odd pages. To solve this problem i try to use `atbegshi` and `geometry` packages. But it takes a strange result: after `\newgeometry` executed page layout frame (`geometry` option) changed, but document text placed at original layout. Same result with `everyshi` package.

Using `\newgeometry` with `everypage` package also take strange result: position of text layout changed, but text layout size is saved original; frame is not changed.

Code example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\newgeometry{noheadfoot,nomarginpar,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,inner=1cm,outer=1cm}}

\begin{document}
    \par AAAA
    \vfill
    \par BBB
    \newpage
    \par CCC
    \vfill
    \par DDD
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: strange page layout]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you can change the margins shifting the block left and right but you can not change the textwidth at a page break. tex sets the text first and then later chops it into pages, adding head and foot, so the text is already broken into lines before it is allocated to a page. You can change it at a forced page break such as \newpage or \clearpage but not at shipout which is too late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example. Though this is unconventional, it may solve your problem.

`\oddgeometryeven{}{}` puts a `\newgeometry{}` at the beginning of each page. The first argument is for odd pages, the second for even ones.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter
\let\@@outputpage\@outputpage
\def\@outputpage{\expandafter\@thisgeometry\@@outputpage}
\def\oddgeometryeven#1#2{%
    \gdef\@thisgeometry{%
    \ifodd\thepage
        \newgeometry{#1}%
    \else
        \newgeometry{#2}%
    \fi}
}
\makeatother

\oddgeometryeven{left=5mm}{top=5mm}

\begin{document}

Page 1 (left=5mm)

\newpage

Page 2 (top=5mm)

\newpage

Page 3 (left=5mm)

\newpage

Page 4 (top=5mm)

\end{document}
```