# Printing on larger page to be cut to smaller paper

Tags: paper-size, crop

I have a normal printer that prints A4 (297x210mm) papers, but occasionally I want to print text that is to end up on smaller paper than that. For that I think I can cut the paper afterwards to get the desired paper size (and for that I cut with a simple pair of scissors).

So what I would want out of LaTeX is to typeset the document for a smaller papersize (for example 250x180mm), but output a PDF for A4 paper with a rectangle showing where the paper is to be cut. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Will your text have headers, footers and side-notes? Will it be a book or other twosided document? I think you have to give more information to be able to get an appropriate on your needs answer. (A MWE would be better: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578 and you don't have to worry about the sizes on this...)

Comment: Off-topic: @Cragfelt he is a member for days now :P On-topic: If you print behind the page (dupplex) we also have to know

Comment: @koleygr Not at TeX.SE. As you can see in his profile, this is his first interaction here. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a red line that has to completely removed:

(It is designed for duplex printing)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bophook}

%%%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213233/120578 to change geometry on odd and even pages
\makeatletter
\let\@@outputpage\@outputpage
\def\@outputpage{\expandafter\@thisgeometry\@@outputpage}
\def\oddgeometryeven#1#2{%
    \gdef\@thisgeometry{%
    \ifodd\thepage
        \newgeometry{#1}%
    \else
        \newgeometry{#2}%
    \fi}
}
\makeatother
% Every size is increased by 15 mm as a real margin inside desired area
\oddgeometryeven{left=15mm,right=45mm,top=15mm,bottom=62mm}{left=45mm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=62mm} 
%%%% End from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213233/120578 to change geometry on odd and even pages

\AtBeginPage{%
\ifodd\thepage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (A) at (current page.north east);
    \coordinate (C) at (current page.south west);
    \coordinate (B) at (current page.south east);
    \draw[line width=1mm, red,inner sep=0]
    ([xshift=-29.5mm]A) -- ([yshift=46.5mm,xshift=-29.5mm]B); % Sizes to cut the page
    \draw[line width=1mm, red,inner sep=0]
    ([yshift=46.5mm]C) -- ([yshift=46.5mm,xshift=-29.5mm]B); % Sizes to cut the page
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (A) at (current page.north west);
    \coordinate (C) at (current page.south west);
    \coordinate (B) at (current page.south east);
    \draw[line width=1mm, red,inner sep=0]
    ([xshift=29.5mm]A) -- ([yshift=46.5mm,xshift=29.5mm]C); % Sizes to cut the page
    \draw[line width=1mm, red,inner sep=0]
    ([yshift=46.5mm,xshift=29.5mm]C) -- ([yshift=46.5mm]B); % Sizes to cut the page
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi
}

\title{My Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{test}
\lipsum*[1-3]\footnote{test footnote}
\subsection{test 2}
\lipsum[1-15]
\section{test 3}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I have used the answer from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213233/120578 for changing geometry between odd and even pages.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses the `geometry` package's machinery.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,%             % a4: 210mm by 297mm
            layoutsize={180mm,250mm},   % width,height
            layoutoffset={15mm,23.5mm}, % center on A4 page
            showcrop]%                  % show cropmarks
           {geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for filler text
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

The parameters of the `layoutoffset` option were chosen so as to center-set the cropped (logical) page on an A4 (physical) page: `15mm=(210mm-180mm)/2` and `23.5mm=(297mm-250mm)/2`.

Other placement options are obviously conceivable. E.g., if you wanted to place the logical page at the top-left of the physical page, so that you'll have to do less cutting with a pair of scissors, you might set `layoutoffset={0mm,0mm}` -- or simply omit this option entirely, as `0mm,0mm` is the default value of the `layoutoffset` parameter.

Comment: A separate remark: With this setup, questions about the layout of the textblock *within* the logical pages can be treated entirely independently. E.g., one could change the document class from `article` to `book` without having to change the `layoutsize`, `layoutoffset`, and `showcrop` parameters.